# GNU Smalltalk Object doesn't understand init

Tags: smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

I have just started learning GNU Smalltalk from [this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/smalltalk/manual/html_node/Defining-methods.html#Defining-methods).
My question is if this page is outdated? In the class creation example it has the `r := super new. ^r init` massage, however running `Object new init` i get

> Object: Object new "<0x7f930e71d800>" error: did not understand #init

I am running the gst version **3.2.91**.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation explicitly says:

> So what we need to do is ask the object to set itself up. By saying r
>   init, we are sending the init message to our new Account. **We’ll
>   define this method in the next section—for now just assume that
>   sending the init message will get our Account set up.**

In other words, you have to keep reading to learn how to define `init`.